# Odoo How to solve return self.models[model_name]

Tags: module, dependencies, odoo, updates

I created 2 custom modules, "projects" and "laboratory".
Laboratory module has one2many field of projects.
Project module has many2one field of laboratory id.

I made some modification of "laboratory" module and when I tried update it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1326, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1314, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-65>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 72, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 634, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 573, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 419, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 315, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 202, in load_module_graph
    registry.init_models(cr, model_names, {'module': package.name}, new_install)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 348, in init_models
    model._auto_init()
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 2482, in _auto_init
    new = field.update_db(self, columns)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 2417, in update_db
    comodel = model.env[self.comodel_name]
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 463, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse(self, (), ())
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'projects'
```

As I googled this error, it seems that I didn't put dependencies of my module "projects".

So, next step was put dependencies:

```
# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base','mail','projects'],
```

And now I get another error which is saying about dependencies on it self:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 624, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 669, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 350, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 915, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1326, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1314, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 387, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-66>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 72, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 634, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 573, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 419, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 315, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
    registry.setup_models(cr)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 255, in setup_models
    model._setup_fields()
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 2690, in _setup_fields
    field.setup_full(self)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 431, in setup_full
    self._setup_regular_full(model)
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 2897, in _setup_regular_full
    comodel = model.env[self.comodel_name]
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 463, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse(self, (), ())
  File "C:\Odoo13\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'laboratory'
```

And when I change dependency and add self module like this:

```
# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
    'depends': ['base','mail','projects','laboratory'],
```

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Could somebody explain why it happens and how I can handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Reason

It is because of "circular dependency". Module "projects" depend on "laboratory". But "laboratory" depend "projects" and it become loop. As a result, module upgrades are not finished, fields are not added and KeyError will be shown. Check those modules in Apps, those will be stuck with only "Cancel Upgrade" button. I am testing this on odoo 11.

## Fix

I can think of a few ways to solve this problem.

- Move both "project" and "laboratory" models to same module.
- Use "many2many" field instead.
- Create another module that depend on both modules and define "one2many" and "many2one" here by inheritance.
- Move one field to another module by inheritance. I mean, for e.g. inherit "Laboratory" and add "projects" field in "Projects" module.

Comment: Oh, now I need to rewrite almost everything((
Any way, thank you for explanation.
Could you also make clear: Do I need add to dependency module each time when I make one of "one2many" or "many2one" or "many2many" fields?

Comment: Yes. If your relational field ("one2many", "many2one", "many2many") use model in another module, you need to add that module as dependency. In my solutions above, you will need to add dependency except the first one.